# Uploading Image to Amazon s3 Retrofit Failure: Timeout

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to upload a file using a custom url in retrofit.

Here's how I'm making the requestBody:

```
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(artifactHeaders.getContentType()), file);
```

Here's the interface:

```
@PUT
Call<ResponseBody> uploadArtifactToAmazon2(@Url String artifactUrl,
                                           @Header("Content-Disposition") String contentDisposition,
                                           @Header("x-amz-server-side-encryption") String xAmzServerSideEncryption,
                                           @Header("x-amz-security-token") String xAmzSecurityToken,
                                           @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                           @Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

But I'm getting this on my log:

```
06-21 10:41:16.354 4760-4808/ 
D/OkHttp: 4�IDATx�<�g�dYv��������j7��cvf�c�5XR����!�06-21 10:41:16.354 4760-4808/D/OkHttp: E�R($�B����"()��D��.�avfz�{zf�Ww�̪J��|/��"������|ޖ�9�?9���Ȧʰ��uv���V���
06-21 10:41:16.504 4760-4808/D/OkHttp: �R>a1�~�`.�>����IOhQS�a�B>��=h0
     [- - - HUNDREDS OF THESE LINES CONTINUE ]
06-21 10:41:16.567 4760-4808/D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/png
06-21 10:41:16.567 4760-4808/D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 669719
```

After a couple of seconds the log gives me this:

```
06-21 10:41:16.626 4760-4808/D/!!!: Cookie Name: __cfduid Cookie Value: df052a1723cd06647966e629e113d4a461466515894 Expiry: Wed, 21-Jun-2017 14:41:14 GMT+00:00
06-21 10:41:28.040 4760-4808/D/!!!: Cookie Name: __cfduid Cookie Value: df052a1723cd06647966e629e113d4a461466515894 Expiry: Wed, 21-Jun-2017 14:41:26 GMT+00:00
06-21 10:41:39.014 4760-4760/D/!!!: Failure Code: timeout
```

Am I getting the image back? What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show us some of your logging code so we can see the source of those lines? And I on a side note..I would HIGHLY recommend using the AWS android lib to update to S3...I previously used Retrofit to upload files to S3 too but was not impressed with performance. Their lib is optimized and uses multipart without you having to rig it up yourself.

Comment: @snkashis I'm seriously considering using the AWS android lib, however the credentials need to use it is coming from our REST API and it'll add more size to the app. I'll post more of the logs.

Comment: I had some of the same concerns however the speed increase was significant enough to justify it(perhaps your uploads are not as large?). Your REST api can deliver cognito credentials the transfer manager uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. It turns out that Retrofit has a default 10 sec. time out (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767460/okhttp-retrofit-default-timeout)).

This interrupts or halts the uploading on retrofit's part.

The characters that I'm seeing on my log (I'm using HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY). The solution is to set the timeout duration:

```
httpClient.readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

My next task would be to either determine how long will it take for the file to be uploaded and using that to set the timeout duration OR handle the timeout event correctly.