# (2.0) Retrofit call inside a Retrofit call causes a Time out exception

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2.0, the code below will log:

`"insertListingImages, SocketOutOfTimeException:TimeOut timeout"`.

Why is it causing a timeout exception? how do I resolve it? The odd thing is that if the retrofit call, `hi()` isn't inside the retrofit call, `insertListingImages()` everything would work fine.

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://IP_ADRESS/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(DatabaseInterface.class);

 retrofit.insertListingImages(imageListingRequest).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                        Log.d("insertListingImages", "Success");
                          retrofit.hi().enqueue(new Callback<Void>(){
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response){
                               Log.d("hiTest", "Success");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                              Log.d("hiTest", "fail: " + t.toString() + " " + t.getMessage());
                            }


                          });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("insertListingImages", "fail: " + t.toString() + " " + t.getMessage());
                    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the connection time out and read timeout by this code. you have to set the custom client for the retrofit

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Here in the above code set the time out as 120 sec, you can change that according to your need

Needed to add below line in the build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

Comment: I'll try this out whenn I cnan; but why did the timeout occur?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767460/okhttp-retrofit-default-timeout