# Is it possible to delay the map method until the connection is complete? RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-java2

```
new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("...").addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).build().create(RetrofitAPI.class).getCategories().map(responseBody -> {

    //I want to handle the JSON here in my way but the result is empty because the map method is called before the connection is completed.

    return responseBody;
}).subscribe(new SingleObserver<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
        Log.w("ABC", "onSubscribe");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) {
        Log.w("ABC", "onSuccess");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
        Log.w("ABC", "onError - " + e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

I'm getting the JSON from the server and I want to handle it in my way inside the map method but the JSON is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Retrofit, the default value for OkHttp is 10 seconds. Retrofit relies
> on the OkHttp default value.

**you should read about retrofit timeout and assign your value for example (30 seconds)**

&& that's will be helpful
[OkHttp/Retrofit default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767460/okhttp-retrofit-default-timeout)